# Facebook login in api version 2.4 not returning email,gender, firstname, lastname etc?

Tags: facebook

I'm using Facebook login API version 2.4 but I can't get email, first name, last name, etc.

It's only giving me owner name and owner id, but older version API I would have gotten all information after the login.

Comment: Please post some code, and more detail with what you're having issues with. This is very low quality for how questions should be structured.

Comment: 1.
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=$appId&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($redirect_url) . "&scope=email&state="  . $_SESSION['state'];

2."https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/oauth/access_token?client_id=$appId&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($redirect_url) . "&client_secret=$appSecretId&code=$code";

3."https://graph.facebook.com/me/?access_token=$access_token";

Comment: in all this url we can't get all information

Comment: but in older version when i use then i will get all information

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Read the docs :-)

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

> **Declarative Fields**
>   To try to improve performance on mobile networks, Nodes and Edges in v2.4 requires that you explicitly request the field(s) you need for your GET requests. For example, GET /v2.4/me/feed no longer includes likes and comments by default, but GET /v2.4/me/feed?fields=comments,likes will return the data. For more details see the docs on how to request specific fields.